# MySQL get start number for search with LIKE and multi pages

Tags: php, mysql, search

at first, i know that this title is confusing, but, I wasn't abe to explain it better. I hop you can forgive me.

for a project, I have built a small "search". It just selects every row that is LIKE %query%. Depends on the query, there can be multiple rows. Much more than fit on one page. But with my page system, just set a limit for entry’s and only choose entry’s their id is more than (page-1)*entrysPerPage.

But in this way, I have the, absolute understandable, problem, that in the request for page 2 I got results from page 1. It's because not every result on page 1 without filter is used in page 1 when I filter. But on filtered page 2 I think, I can start again with (page-1)*entrysPerPage. Does anyone have an idea how do I can get the start number?

I hope my question is understandable

Thanks, allot

Cripi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let

```
$entryPerPage = 10;
$page = 1;
```

then

```
$start = ($page-1)*$entryPerPage; // $start = 0;
```

then your query is

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table_name LIMIT $start, $entryPerPage";
```